# basic authentication with Node.js and restify

Tags: javascript, node.js, basic-authentication, restify

I'm currently developing a RESTful web service with NodeJS and [restify](https://github.com/mcavage/node-restify).

I have everything up and running with node-mysql for the database, but I also would like to implement HTTP Basic authentication.

I only did this once with Apache and an `.htaccess` file.

But here the webserver comes with restify and I start it like this:

```
var server = restify.createServer({
  name: 'my webservice'
});
```

There is a Authentication Parser Plugin listed in the restify documentation (http://mcavage.me/node-restify/#Bundled-Plugins) but I can't figure out how to use it.

The `req.username` value is always set to anonymous, even when I use `http://user:pass@url...`.

The best thing would be if I could use it with a `.htpasswd` file to store/access the user and pass.

Does anyone know how to implement this with restify or another module?

Answer (score 6):

Finally I found a way to do it without any additional modules.

First I send the correkt header:

```
var auth = req.headers['authorization'];
res.statusCode = 401;
res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="Secure Area"');
res.end('need creds');
```

Then I check the user and pass and if its ok then send the correct status code

```
res.statusCode = 200;  // OK
```

If the password is not correct:

```
  res.statusCode = 401; // Force them to retry authentication
  res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="Secure Area"');
  res.end('<html><body>You shall not pass</body></html>');
```

This works pretty well. I only have some trouble to read the .htpasswd and the crypted password.
Does anyone know how I can check a plain password against a .htpasswd file?

Comment: Do you think that it could work also in my case : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287897/how-is-filled-request-header-authorization ? Or I should change my old code and use only "restify" extensions?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Passport.js](http://passportjs.org/). It supports [Basic HTTP](http://passportjs.org/guide/basic-digest/) as one of the authentication schemes.

Comment: looks promising... I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

> The req.username value is always set to anonymous, even when I use
>   http: //user:pass@url....

The documentation seems to suggest that it expects the credentials in the header not in the url, you might need to use Curl or some other tool besides a browser to make headers with authorization headers.

Comment: Ok... I thought that they will be send in the header even when I put them in the url.

Comment: @nico - I guess a browser could have that feature, but you can't be sure.  I've never see the url format you show in use.

Answer (score -4):

With express you can do something like this:

```
var auth = express.basicAuth(function(user, pass) {
    return (user == "admin" && pass == "1234");
},'Super duper secret area');

app.get('/test', auth, function(req, res){
    ...
});
```

[expressjs.com](http://expressjs.com)

Comment: I don't want to use express. It has too much included that I do not need... thats why I chose restify.js