# How is filled request.header.authorization?

Tags: node.js, express, authorization, restify

I'm passing from express to restify and I wrote a module to check my authorization that used express-session and before it worked well.

Now, on restify, the request.headers.authorization return undefined so my question is:
can I add some code to tell to restify to fill this field?

Comment: It should be `request.headers.authorization`. Do you know for sure that whatever client is calling your code actually supplies an authorization header?

Comment: @HeadCode : you are right! However, what do you mean? If do I know that all calls will arrive from smartphone, for example? If it is correct, so I would create the api most flexible as possible so the answer is no.

Comment: I have a doubt, who does fill the headers? My server api or client call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, sorry for my illiteracy in autentication/authorization process!
The problem was that I didn't send any headers on "authorization" request!
Now it works without any new code.